# Change format of a range of columns rather than one at a time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that takes the format of a cell and applies it to another cell.  The code I'm using is:

```
var backColor1 = sheet.getRange("Config!C30");
var cbgColors = backColor1.getBackgrounds();
bRange2.setBackgrounds(cbgColors);
```

bRange2 is set as the cell I want to apply the background colour too.  This works, but I'm doing several hundreds of cells using a loop and to achieve this each cell is drawn individually, which takes time.

Is there a way to apply the background colour to a range of cells? Even a number of rows or columns at the same time would be more efficient than the way I'm currently doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const newColor = ss.getRange('Config!C30').getBackground();
  const rangesA1 = ['Data1!A1:A', 'Data1!D4:F42', 'Data2!A1:ZZ'];
  rangesA1.map(rangeA1 => ss.getRange(rangeA1))
    .forEach(range => {
      const colors = range.getValues().map(row => row.map(cell => newColor));
      range.setBackgrounds(colors);
    });
```

Comment: I've created a blank sheet and added this into a function but it doesn't appear to work?

Comment: Does your testing spreadsheet include sheets named 'Config', 'Data1' and 'Data2'? If not, add them, or modify the code to refer to the sheet names you are actually using.

Comment: I didn't realise those were referencing tabs.  I've now added them.

I receive the following error: Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setBackgrounds.

Comment: Fixed the code to create a 2D colors array — `Range.setBackgrounds()` does not seem to auto-expand scalars the way `Range.setValues()` does.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use `getBackground` instead of `getBackgrounds` (without the final "s")

There are two variations of each function.

- `getBackground` & `getBackgrounds`
- `setBackground` & `setBackgrounds`

Consult the deatils in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html

In a nutshell, with the 'singluar' versions, the `get` will return a string value such as `#ffff00` and the `set` will also take a single string.

With the `plural` versions, the `get` will return a two dimensional array of string values, i.e.:

```
[
[#ffff00, #ffffff, #ffffff],
[#ffffff, #ffffff, #ffffff],
[#ffffff, #ffffff, #ffffff],
[#ffffff, #ffffff, #ffffff],
[#ffffff, #ffffff, #00ff00],
[#ffffff, #ffffff, #ffffff]
]
```

This one for example represents a range of three columns and six rows. With the plural version of the `set` method, `setBackgrounds` the range you call it on need to *match exactly* the size of the two dimensional array. So for the above example `A1:C6` would be a valid range. This gives you more control, in case you want to color a whole range in various colors, but to do it with one command.

Whereas with the singluar version `setBackground` you can select a large range, and then pass it one string value, and it will set the whole range to that color.

Your example might look like:

```js
var backColor1 = sheet.getRange("Config!C30");
var cbgColors = backColor1.getBackground();
var bRange2 = sheet.getRange("A1:Z10")
bRange2.setBackground(cbgColors);
```

#### Reference

- [Range Methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html)